# (We are talking about a man with a head with no hair at all) Do I say: "The man has a bald head" or "The man has the head bald"

Tags: grammar

(We are talking about a man with a head with no hair at all) Do I say: "The man has a bald head"

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the reason for confusion. Would you say you are mainly asking about the word order, or the use of the article, or both? Why do these two options ("has a bold head" and "has the head bold") both seem to you like they might be correct?

Comment: "The man has a bald head" is fine but maybe a little more commonly, you would say "The man is bald." And yes, note that this is bAld not bOld.

Comment: ooooops sorry, I meant bald

Comment: You can "edit" your question to correct the spelling.

Comment: Does the article "The" change the sense of the question?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under your question to change _bold_ to _bald._ It is humorous in English, for some reason that escapes me, to describe a head as _bold_ (especially one which is glabrous.)

Answer (score 1):

As JamieB noted, the usual way of expressing this idea is "the man is bald."

It is also OK to say "The man has a bald head." It just sounds a bit redundant since "bald" already implies that you're talking about his head.

You cannot say "The man has the head bald," for two reasons.

1. The definite article is not appropriate in this situation (a body part after the verb "have"). Indefinites are generally used in this context. This also applies to hair, for example: we say "he has red hair," not "he has the red hair."
2. The order of the noun and adjective is wrong. Attributive adjectives in English usually come before the noun. For this reason, "the head bald" is not grammatical ("the bald head" would be grammatical, but it is not idiomatic because of the definite article).